# Creating duplicate rows while updating a single column with multiindex

Tags: pandas

I am new to pandas. I have a dataframe that keeps tracks of units sold and associated prices for a number of products. I want to create rows for all products that will be for months up until month 12, copying the data from 'price' and 'units'.

**INPUT**

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', index_col=None)
print(df.to_string())

        name location  month  price  units
0  Product A        X     10   2.97      2
1  Product A        Y     10   2.67      3
2  Product B        X     10   2.67      4
```

**OUTPUT**

```
df

        name location  month  price  units
0  Product A        X     10   2.97      2
1  Product A        X     11   2.97      2
2  Product A        X     12   2.97      2
3  Product A        Y     10   2.67      3
4  Product A        Y     11   2.67      3
5  Product A        Y     12   2.67      3
6  Product B        X     10   2.67      4
7  Product B        X     11   2.67      4
8  Product B        X     12   2.67      4
```

I believe I need to create a MultiIndex from 'name', 'location', and 'month'. I am able to create the desired effect for one column, but not multiple at the same time.

My code for creating this for simply units is:

```
df = df.set_index(['name', 'location', 'month'])
u = df.units.unstack()

for i in range(10,13):
    u[i] = u[10]

u = u.stack().reset_index()
u = u.rename(columns={0:'units'})
u
```

Which results in

```
        name location  month  units
0  Product A        X     10      2
1  Product A        X     11      2
2  Product A        X     12      2
3  Product A        Y     10      3
4  Product A        Y     11      3
5  Product A        Y     12      3
6  Product B        X     10      4
7  Product B        X     11      4
8  Product B        X     12      4
```

I can accomplish my desired result by repeating my code for price and then merging the two dataframes. However, this seems inelegant and is inefficient if there are many columns I wish to copy over. How can I get my desired results more elegantly or by taking advantage of advanced pandas functionality?

Comment: How did you output this ----+----- tables?

Comment: I'm using an ascii table to represent the dataframe. If there's a better way to produce dataframes for StackOverflow answers, please advise.

Comment: Yes, the output of `print(df.to_string())` is usually preferred, that way it can be read using `pd.read_clipboard()`.

Comment: Thank you @AndyHayden, I have updated my post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC , may be something like below:

```
months = list(range(1,13))
a = 13-df.loc[df.month.isin(months),'month']
df_new=pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,a,axis=0),columns=df.columns)

df_new.month=df_new.groupby(['name','location'])['month'].apply(lambda x : (x.duplicated().cumsum()+df_new.month).dropna())

print(df_new)


         name    location  month price units
0   Product A       X         10  2.97     2
1   Product A       X         11  2.97     2
2   Product A       X         12  2.97     2
3   Product A       Y         10  2.67     3
4   Product A       Y         11  2.67     3
5   Product A       Y         12  2.67     3
6   Product B       X         10  2.67     4
7   Product B       X         11  2.67     4
8   Product B       X         12  2.67     4
```